# Unity crashed after nvidia driver install

Tags: 12.10, nvidia

On fresh Ubuntu install, the first thing i did was install the latest NVIDIA drivers. After reboot, unity disapeared. Only the mouse and the wallpaper were there. 
I was using 64-bit Ubuntu. How to fix this?
PS i have desktop

Comment: If you have a laptop, you probably have a Nvidia Optimus laptop. See http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969

Comment: You did not mention what hardware you have...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the nvidia drivers you installed by typing 'sudo apt-get purge nvidia*' (This will remove all nvidia drivers installed), then reboot. If Unity is still not back at that point, type 'ccsm' to open Compiz (The window manager) and scroll down and manually re-enable the 'Ubuntu Unity Plugin', and resolve all the conflicts by disabling the conflicting plugins. Then reboot again, and it should be good